# Cordova iOS download file to iPhones general "Downloads" folder

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, download

on iOS, is there ANY method that can allow an app to download a file to the iPhones general "Downloads" folder that the user can find on their iPhone (IE: using the iPhones `Files` app  The `Files` app opens allowing users to navigate the iCloud storage OR the local `On My iPhone`.)

I have written four different methods that all succeed in downloading files to app sub-folders, but the users can't get to them because there is no way for the user to navigate to the apps sub-folders.

`cordova-plugin-file-transfer` - allows you to download files to app sub-folders.

`inAppBrowser` - doesn't allow download links to work, iOS prevents it

The only thing I have found is using a browser like Safari or Chrome to download the file...but this is an ugly solution that takes the user out of our app AND it requires exposing files on our web server requiring additional coding to only allow authorized users to download the selected files.

I can't be the only person with this issue....is there not a proper method to allow files to be downloaded to a publicly accessible place?

I mean, if iOS wants to completely sandbox apps, at least create symbolic links to downloaded files in an app download folder that is then symbolically linked back to the main `Downloads` folder.  So the user would see something like:

`Downloads --> MyAppDownloadFolder --> downloadedFile.pdf`

So when users click to open the `MyAppDownloadFolder` they would be opening up the app sandboxed download folder.

Comment: In your `info.plist` add the keys `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` with a value of `true` .  Then your app's `documents` folder will appear in the Files app under your app name in "On my iPhone"

Comment: @Paulw11 - ARE YOU F'ING KIDDING ME?!!!   THIS WORKED!  Dude, I have combed dozens and dozens and dozens (and dozens more) of posts trying to get this to work....no where, not ONCE are these `info.plist` keys mentioned.  $hit....its not even mentioned in the damn `cordova-plugin-file` - which IS the Cordova defacto guide to interacting with the various OS fileSystems.  Please make this the answer so I can give you every bit of credit for ending 2+ years of frustration.

Comment: @Paulw11 - msg me and I will send you funds for 2 two cases of your favorite beer.  Not kidding!

Comment: Historically these plist values were used to expose an app's documents folder via iTunes (they pre-date the existence of the Files app on iOS). When Apple added the Files app then they used these values to also show your app's documents in files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to save your files outside the Sandbox; You would have to use a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to let the user specify a save location.

What you can do, easily, is add `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` keys to your info.plist with boolean `true` values.

This will then show your app's documents folder under your app name in "On my iPhone" in the Files app.

Comment: Dude....you win the Internet for the day!  Its ironic that even in my OP that I even postulate the iOS should at least implement symlinks so users can get to files in the sandbox.  And sure as heck...it already exists; just seems that hardly ANYONE knows about it.

Comment: Uh...now that I know that these exist for iOS, it then begs the question:  Do similar preferences exist for Android?  Right now, we can download files external sources on Android, but its not guaranteed for all devices and not guaranteed that Android will continue to allow it.   which would then only leave the apps internal sandboxed documents directories.

Comment: You could find more info and the feature request in this GitHub [comment](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/560#issuecomment-1457359007)