# Saving data from iOS app into CSV file but can't find file

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I am trying to save the data generated from an iOS app into a CSV file. My code seems to be working and it shows a message in the console that the data is saved to the file. The problem is that I can't find that CSV file either on the iPhone or my MacBook.

Can you please help with this?

Here is my code:

```
let data = [
    ["name": "Sara", "age": 30],
    ["name": "John", "age": 25]
]

var csvString = "Name,Age\n"

for row in data {
    let name = row["name"]!
    let age = row["age"]!
    csvString.append("\(name),\(age)\n")
}

let fileName = "name_age_data.csv"
let docDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let fileURL = docDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

try! csvString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

print("Data saved to \(fileName)")
```

How to save the data into CSV file that I can find on my MacBook?

Comment: The file is being saved in your apps sandbox documents directory. You can either provide the ability for the user to export the file via `UIDocumentPickerViewController` or expose your documents folder in the files app and finder when connected to a Mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656618/cordova-ios-download-file-to-iphones-general-downloads-folder/75657360#75657360

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Isn't there any way for me only as a developer to access the CSV file? I don't need the participants to access the files or share them.

Comment: Change `print("Data saved to \(fileName)")` to `print("Data saved to \(fileURL)")` and you will see the full path to the file. Of course this is only useful when running the app in a simulator.

Comment: @NA16 - Do you only want to download the CSV file from a build that you have installed on your own device via Xcode?

Comment: @paulw11 yes. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want a specific solution to access the file from a device that you are testing on, rather than a generic solution that allows users to import/export a file from your app, you can use Xcode.

- From the Xcode *Window* menu, select *Devices and simulators*
- Connect your device via USB and select it from the device list
- Find your app in the list of *Installed apps* and select it
- Click on the *...* in a circle on the bottom toolbar
- Select *Download Container* from the pop up menu
- Right click on the downloaded container and select "Show Package Contents"
- You will find your app's *Documents* directory under *AppData*